# Storing arrays vs associative tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked in a lot of places and on this site and I am at a development block. I'm making a website and using MySQL to store stuff using PHP. Part of this website is I want to store the types of games a user plays which would be split up into three categories, Game / Platform / Username.

As a coder, I want to make a set of parallel vectors/arrayLists to hold these things, since the amount of games they might play is undefined. I was thinking of making a table but every time I try it doesn't show up in the database.  From what I found, people say to not use arrays for databases since that ruins the purpose of a database. How would I store these fields dynamically?

Also from what I found, there is a thing called `serialize()` which I don't understand exactly how to use it, I can look that up. However, people say that it's not the "proper" way of doing something like this, but they could be wrong.

Comment: Could you not have a `category` table, and link it from `user` via a foreign key? In what way does such a table "not show up in the database"?

Comment: People who say serialization isn't the proper way of doing something like this aren't wrong, it is a very bad approach making it complex and inefficient to search or update that data

Comment: Serialisation _can_ be useful for performance increases, but you need to know what the limitations are, and as Mark says it is usually the wrong answer.

Comment: Serialisation is fine if the thing being serialised doesn't need to be searched or indexed

Comment: The `serialize()` approach would be a solution, but you should really look into using multiple tables for this. Have a `user` table which references a `game` table which references a `platform` table. Read up on database normalization from something like this: http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/

Comment: Part of the website is that you want to search for people who play similar games / platforms etc. So `serialize()` doesn't seem to be the proper way. I will try the reference table thing that sounds like the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Serialize takes an array and converts it to a string. You can then take that string and save it a single table entry.

It might go something like this:

```
$user = array();

$games = array();

$games[] = array("Game" => "Chess", "Platform" => "Computer", "UserName" => "ChessMaster");
$games[] = array("Game" => "Checkers", "Platform" => "Mobile", "UserName" => "CheckersPlayer");
$games[] = array("Game" => "Solitaire", "Platform" => "Computer", "UserName" => "SolitaireUser");

$user[] = $games;
```

Now in order to save the entry into a database you convert the user array into a string with serialize().

```
$serializedUser = serialize($user);
```

Which will output this:

```
//echo $serializedUser;

a:1:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"Game";s:5:"Chess";s:8:"Platform";s:8:"Computer";s:8:"UserName";s:11:"ChessMaster";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"Game";s:8:"Checkers";s:8:"Platform";s:6:"Mobile";s:8:"UserName";s:14:"CheckersPlayer";}i:2;a:3:{s:4:"Game";s:9:"Solitaire";s:8:"Platform";s:8:"Computer";s:8:"UserName";s:13:"SolitaireUser";}}}
```